# How to remove users from a copy of a database SQLite?

Tags: django, database, sqlite

Now I am hosting my django project on github. My friend wants to move this project to his computer. I want him not to waste time populating the database, but to install a copy of mine.
I do like this: `python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json`

Does this json store usernames and passwords? If yes, how to remove them?

I want my friend to create his own superuser on his computer, and take only test data from the SQLite database copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove auth models by excluding app with the good option:

```bash
python manage.py dumpdata --exclude=auth > datadump.json
```